# Proper way to use TypeScript based NPM packages in an Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, angular2-aot

I have an angular2 project using SystemJS.  I want to use [ng2-google-place-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-place-autocomplete).  The thing is, when I install this package all the contents are ts files.  I haven't encountered this before.

It seems by default TypeScript will exclude `node_module` files (for good reason).

So to get it working I installed TypeScript as a module itself, include it in my `index.html` file:
`<script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>`

...and then I set up SystemJS to transpile it:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },       
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'build',
//Lots of stuff in this file here that I cropped out...

      'ng2-google-place-autocomplete' : 'npm:ng2-google-place-autocomplete'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-google-place-autocomplete' :{
        main:'./index.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
//A bunch more stuff cropped out
    }
  });
})(this);
```

It works.  The thing is, I don't really want to transpile it in the browser.  More urgently right now, if I then try to use AOT on my app (via `ngc`), I get errors because it tries to compile TypeScript itself and causes conflicts `Error at /Development/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts:21:14: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.`

I apologize in that I don't even know what avenue to pursue to best solve this issue - I'm not sure if this is a Typescript config thing, or if I should be setting up SystemJS differently.

I imagine the easy solution to at least solve the AOT issue is to just use a CDN for typescript so it isn't in my `node_modules` at all, but the browser can still reference it to transpile.  ...but that still seems kinda hacky and the browser is still doing extra work for no reason.

What's the real solution?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Why not use the systemjs-builder to create a bundle of the dependency as a single JavaScript file on disk and then import that? Also angular-cli ripped out support for SystemJS, and may they regret it indefinitely... Someone on angular-cli repo the other day asked for rollup-optimizations, and I was thinking, SystemJS has that out of the box.

Comment: @Volodymyr Bilyachat I was worried that would be the answer.  So I guess from here out if you are using angular you are using cli, and if not, you are on your own.  I guess I'll have to migrate to webpack.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I think in the long run I may as well just give in and start using the cli.  I agree what you propose would work, but I worry that the longer I go on without giving into the CLI the more complexity I'm going to make for myself.

Comment: The angular CLI is definitely not required. Webpack is also not required. There are lots of successful systemjs projects out there that are working fine. I don't like the CLI and I wouldn't use it. I feel like whether you were using SystemJS or are using Webpack the CLI abstracts away way too many useful features. The really scary thing is Google internally users neither. They use a customized version of TypeScript, which they pipe into tsickle, which they in turn pipe into the Google closure compiler.

Comment: My earlier comments may have been confusing what I meant was that the angular CLI project is now based on Webpack instead of SystemJS. However Angular itself, to its credit, does not require the use of either. There are setups using all kinds of tool chains from Rollup to RequireJS and they do in fact work. AOT support is a completely different story. Basically what it supports and what it will support are completely undocumented and in flux. It requires a customized programming language which is a subset of TypeScript but also adds semantics that are incompatible with ECMAScript. This is bad

Comment: @WillyC well its not true, reason why I always suggest to start with cli is that as a developers we should solve customer problem fast. And the problem with fronted world is that there is too many tools and too many options where you need to spend ages to understand how to use them properly. Cli gives you quick start and later if you need you can extend it.